# Not Acceptable error showing while calling response from ajax in SPRING

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, spring

I am trying to get response in form of json array from controller class. When I tried to send request from javascript, I get "Not Acceptable" error. Please help to find b ug in my code.

This is my controller's code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajaxvalue", method = { RequestMethod.GET }, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public @ResponseBody Map<String, String> geResourceList(String name){
        logger.info("getAllResources() from ajax begins: ");
        Map<String, String> resourceMap = null;
        try {
            logger.info("getAllResources() from ajax begin: ");
            resourceMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            List<ResourceModel> resourceList = resourceService
                    .getAllResources();
            java.util.Iterator<ResourceModel> resourceIterator = resourceList.iterator();
            while (resourceIterator.hasNext()) {
                ResourceModel model = resourceIterator.next();
                resourceMap.put("" + model.getResourceType(),
                        model.getName());
                logger.info("" + model.getResourceType(),
                        model.getName());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.debug("Error while getting location in ajax request:"
                    + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }logger.info("getAllResources() from ajax ENDS: ");
        return resourceMap;
    }
```

This is my jquery code.

```
jQuery.ajax({
url: '<c:url value='/learningresources/ajaxvalue'/>',
type: 'GET',
dataType:'json',
contentType: "application/json",
cache:false,
success:function(response){
    alert(response);
},
error:function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert("error: "+errorThrown);
}
});
```

Comment: Check your network tab in your google chrome. You must return json from your controller.

Comment: Are you using maven or adding depending manually?

Comment: Adding depending manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely because of not having jackson library in class path, the following are two solutions depending on your configuration.

if you are using maven then add the following dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are manually adding the jars then goto [jackson download page](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload) and download version required according to your spring version.

Make sure you get appropriate jackson version based on your spring version.

Answer (score 0):

try to add request header "Accept"  to ajax call.

```
 headers: {
    'Accept':'application/json',
 }
```